# how to find the max id from a generic list

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, generic-list

i m getting a collection of data in list's object. And from this list i want to get the maximum id.`

```
Dim objinfo As List(Of AlbumInfo) = objPhotos.GetPhotos_Alb_ID(Me.ModuleId, hdd_AlbID.Value)

Dim Photo_Image As String = ""

Dim str As String = Photo_Image & fu_Photo.PostedFile.FileName.Substring(fu_Photo.PostedFile.FileName.LastIndexOf("."))
If objinfo.Count >= 1 Then
   Photo_Image = Convert.ToString(hdd_AlbID.Value) + "_" + Convert.ToString(objinfo.Item("0").Photo_Id + 1)
Else
   Photo_Image = Convert.ToString(hdd_AlbID.Value) + "_" + Convert.ToString("1")
End If
```

this returns the "0"th positions id from `Convert.ToString(objinfo.Item("0").Photo_Id + 1)`
but i want to get the last item's id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you specify *max* in the title, and *last* in the question, so here's both:

Max:

```
Photo_Image = hdd_AlbID.Value.ToString() & "_" & _
    objinfo.Max(Function(o) o.Photo_Id) _
           .Photo_Id.ToString()
```

Last:

```
Photo_Image = hdd_AlbID.Value.ToString() & "_" & _
    objinfo.Last().Photo_Id.ToString()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Max](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535031.aspx) extension method. For example,

```
...
maxPhotoId = objInfo.Max(Function(photo) photo.Photo_Id).Photo_Id
...
```